# Second order ODE with cubic term -- explicit solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there an explicit solution to the differential equation
$$
f''(x)-f'(x)-f(x)^3 =0.
$$

Comment: Mathematica can't find one, which is not to say it doesn't exist, only that it will be very "tricky" to find, if there is one. Do you have more context you could post?

Comment: Is this $$(f(x))^3$$ or $$f^{(3)}(x)$$

Answer (score 3):

Maple doesn't find an "explicit" solution either, but there is a "reduction" to first order: if $t = f(x)$ and $s = f'(x)$, then

$$ s \dfrac{ds}{dt} - s = t^3$$

and we can recover $x$ from

$$ x = \int \dfrac{dt}{s} $$

Of course the constant $f(x) = 0$ is a solution.